Kafka auto commit improve choppy performance
Given the stack: Kafka, Confluent.Kafka v.2.2.0
we tried committing updates individually, which resulted in pretty bad performance of ~150ms per update. Since our update processing is synchronous, we decided to try Kafka auto commit feature, which gave us an performance boost by ~30-40%, but every 6-7th update (irrespective of the timespan within which they occur) is taking considerably longer. We understand that auto commit = commit called periodically by Kafka but how do we minimize the impact of it? Are there any additional settings which can be tweaked to improve the performance?
Sample stats before:
150
120
160
140
150
Sample stats after:
30
40
290
40
50
30
470
